How to create a file in another server using T-SQL
I have 2 servers; one server hosts a SQL Server (which is a Windows machine), and the other one is a linux system.
I want to export the data from the SQL Server instance to linux system. While I was executing this code shown here, I get an error.
This is my code:
DECLARE @LV_FILE_PATH varchar(200) ='opt\shared\data\testtextfile3.txt'
DECLARE @LV_SQLTXT varchar(2000)='"SELECT top 100 * from sales"'
DECLARE @LV_CMDTXT VARCHAR(2000)

SET @LV_CMDTXT =  'BCP ' + @LV_SQLTXT + ' QUERYOUT "' + @LV_FILE_PATH + '" -c -U -T -S -r\n'

EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL @LV_CMDTXT

The error I get is this:

SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to open BCP host data-file

Could you please help me with this?

Don't do this at all in SQL Server, is the real solution. Run bcp from the command line, don't use xp_cmdshell as a crutch like this.

Not to mention, that path doesn't look complete. It's lacking a device letter (such as C:\\``). If it's a Linux path, optis in the root and also Linux uses/for paths; so it should be/opt/shared/data/testtextfile3.txt`. Backslash is an escape character in bash, so that path simply isn't a valid Unix path.

Also, you need to specify a fully qualified file path for the output file parameter.

better to use bcp or something else from linux and get your file that way, otherwise you probably need to setup a share and give it correct rights for sql server to be able to read them, which is a pain in the endterior

Use bcp or sqlcmd executing on Linux to pull the data rather than trying to push the data from the SQL Server process. This avoids having to setup Kerberos authentication, trusts and file shares.

Create and deploy an SSIS package to do the work, then you can initiate the package in a variety of ways such as from Visual Studio, direct from SSMS or even from a stored proc if you wanted users to be able to do the task via an app.

Please check if the ODBC Driver 17 is added to your ODBC Data Sources.
To me, doing this fixed this issue.

